# Get posts all posts by Tag / URL Wordpress On Post / Pge

Tags: wordpress, list, post, plugins, tags

For take posts by tag and list post and pages.

```css
add_action('the_content', 'shortCodeEasyFilter');
function shortCodeEasyFilter($content) {
    if (is_single()) {
        $finds = getInbetweenStrings($content);
        if (count($finds) > 0) {
            $content = "<style>
            .shortlink {
                margin: 4px;
             font-size: 18px;
             background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#0c6fb1,#0c6fb1);
             color: #FFFFFF !important;
             padding: 8px;
             border-radius: 8px;
             position: relative;
             display: block;
             margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
            .shortlink:hover {
             color: #FFFFFF !important;
                opacity: 0.8;
                text-decoration: none
            }
            .shortlink * {
                display: inline;
            }
            .shortlink h3 {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .shortlink a {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                margin: 0
            }
            </style>".$content;
        }
        foreach($finds as $code) {
            foreach(explode(",", $code) as $codepart) {
                $output = '';
                query_posts(array(
                    "post_status" => "publish",
                    "tag_id" => $codepart
                ));
                while(have_posts()) {
                    the_post();
                    $title = get_the_title();
                    $link = get_the_permalink();
                    $output .= "<h3 style='margin-bottom: 5px'><a class='shortlink' href='$link' title='$title'><i class='fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right'></i>&nbsp;$title</a></h3>";
                }
                wp_reset_query();
                $content = str_replace("[etikonu]".$code."[/etikonu]", $output, $content);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
 
function getInbetweenStrings($str){
    preg_match_all('%\[etiketlist\](.*?)\[/etiketlist\]%i', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    return $matches[1];
}
 
?>
```

This code lists the last articles in the first place. I want to make the first articles in the first place and I want to make alphabetical listings too. So I have to make 3 different lists. Can you help me?
Thank you...